# Comparing two hash values perl

Tags: perl, hash, compare

I am working on perl after a break. if I am not clear please ask .

I have a hash of hash.

```
REST123=>{'test' => 'A',
          'test1'=> 'B',
          'test2'=> 'C'
          'test3'=> 'D'
         }
REST425=>{'test' => 'A',
          'test1'=> 'C',
          'test2'=> 'C'
          'test3'=> 'B'
         }

REST234=>{'test' => 'A',
          'test1'=> 'B',
          'test2'=> 'C'
          'test3'=> 'D'
         }
```

I would like to compare the ABCD  among all the REST* .The REsult  should be something like this.

```
REST123 REST425 4 1(mismatch) 
REST123 REST234 4 0 (mismatch)
```

I tried copying hash on another but that doesn't work. Any easy way of accessing them to compare would be really appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 0):

I had to guess a bit, but my crystal ball told me you need the following code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash
    = (
       REST123 => { test  => 'A',
                    test1 => 'B',
                    test2 => 'C',
                    test3 => 'D',
                  },
       REST425 => { test  => 'A',
                    test1 => 'C',
                    test2 => 'C',
                    test3 => 'B',
                  },
       REST234 => { test  => 'A',
                    test1 => 'B',
                    test2 => 'C',
                    test9 => 'D',
                  },
      );

for my $k1 (keys %hash) {
    for my $k2 (grep $k1 gt $_, keys %hash) {
        my %h;
        $h{$_} ++ for map keys %{ $hash{$_} }, $k1, $k2;
        my @same = grep $h{$_} == 2, keys %h;
        print join ' ', $k1, $k2, scalar @same,
            scalar grep $hash{$k1}{$_} ne $hash{$k2}{$_}, @same;
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

Note that it returns 2 mismatches, not 1, as `'B' ne 'C'` (test1) and `'D' ne 'B'` (test3).